# SQL BULK INSERT with conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

What i'm trying to do is read a text file and then use `BULK INSERT` to create a table.

This is an example of how the text file looks

```
TIME       DATE         USER_NAME    VALUE

11:10:04   10/02/15     Irene I.     Moosa
```

There are a lot of rows and i mean a lot but sometimes the time is empty or the end character is not just a simple enter and I'm trying to compensate for it

Is something like this possible:

```
BULK INSERT #TEMP FROM 'C:\QPR_Logs\Audit\MetricsServerAudit.txt'
WHERE [TIME] IS NOT NULL WITH (FIELDTERMINATOR =' ', ROWTERMINATOR = '\n')
```

Something like that if it reads a null value that it just skips the line?
For the end character I'm not exactly sure what to use.
Has anyone got any suggestions?

Comment: `BULK INSERT #temporary ....; INSERT INTO #temp SELECT ... FROM #temporary WHERE ....`

Answer (score 0):

Try [OPENROWSET](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190312.aspx).  since you have custom row/column terminators, you might require a format file.

```
select t1.*
from openrowset(bulk 'c:\folder\file1.csv'
        , formatfile = 'c:\folder\values.fmt'
        , firstrow = 2) as t1
where t1.[TIME] is not null
```